# Need help making tab page in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am working on making a page that has multiple tabs each tab has different content in it. I looked online for tutorials and found this site http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery. I have been following it, i have tweaked the settings to how I want it to look however when I try to click on a different tab nothing changes. I am still pretty new to jquery so I am a little confused in that field and I was hoping someone could help me out and let me know what to do.

The problem is that the tab are not switching upon clicking

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./common/res.css"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Room Reservation</title>
</head>
<header>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Stage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Studio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Session</a></li>
        </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <form>
            Room Selection:<br>
            <select name="room">
                <option value="">Select Room</option>
                <option value="stage">Stage Access</option>
                <option value="grip">Grip Closet</option>
                <option value="grid">Grid</option>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <p>Studio</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <p>Session</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


en/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
}

/*----- Tab Links -----*/
/* Clearfix */
.tab-links:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:'';
}

.tab-links li {
    margin:0px 5px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

    .tab-links a {
        padding:9px 15px;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        background:#7FB5DA;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:600;
        color:#4c4c4c;
        transition:all linear 0.15s;
    }

    .tab-links a:hover {
        background:#a7cce5;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#fff;
    color:#4c4c4c;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
.tab-content {
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background:#fff;
}

    .tab {
        display:none;
    }

    .tab.active {
        display:block;
    }ter code here


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
           jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that. I can also add the css if need be. As far as the JQuery it is just what is in that link, however I do not have it in right now since it wasnt working

Comment: @R_Chin — You appear to have skipped steps 2 and 3 of the tutorial you were following.

Comment: @R_Chin — How are you linking the JavaScript to the HTML?

Comment: For some reason that line didn't copy in the code. But I have the js in another file in a common folder so in the common folder so in the header i have <script type="text/javascript" src="./common/tab.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Room Reservation</title>
</head>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active" data-toggle="#tab1">Stage</a></li>
        <li data-toggle="#tab2">Studio</li>
        <li data-toggle="#tab3">Session</li>
    </ul>
</div>`
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <form>
            Room Selection:<br>
            <select name="room">
                <option value="">Select Room</option>
                <option value="stage">Stage Access</option>
                <option value="grip">Grip Closet</option>
                <option value="grid">Grid</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <p>Studio</p>
    </div>`

    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <p>Session</p>
    </div>
</div>
<style>`
`.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.tab-links li {
    margin:0px 5px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:9px 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
    background:#7FB5DA;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#4c4c4c;
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
}
.tab-links li:hover {
    background:#a7cce5;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li.active, li.active:hover {
    background:#fff;
    color:#4c4c4c;
}
.tab-content {
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background:#fff;
 }`

 .tab {
    display:none;
 }

.tab.active {
    display:block;
}`

</style>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.tabs .tab-links li').on('click', function(e)  {
        tabs(jQuery(this).attr('data-toggle'));
        jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });`

        function tabs(tab) {
            jQuery('.tab-content .tab').hide()
            jQuery('.tab-content').find(tab).show();
        }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

First of all you should include jquery library, then correct your html, and use fucntions from start please, be true! :D I suggesting you to not use a tags in tabs

Comment: I added that into the html and it is working and switching the tabs! Thank you. Now however the body of the text is not changing to the correct tab. Is that an html issue?

Comment: can you explain in detail? not sure I understand what do you mean

Comment: When I click on a new tab the content doesnt change. So for example when I click the stage tab it should display different content in the body than when i click the studio tab